# Integer that begins with zero converting to string (and keep that leading zero)

Tags: php, javascript, sql, codeigniter, gps

my problem is this one, I have a javascript code that gets GPS location from a browser. Then, because I can't write those coordinates to SQL database from javascript and I can't send it directly to php, I go to the controller "site" and it's method "writeToDatabase" and I also add 4 segments to URL that are actually those coordinates that I got from javascript..

so in javascript I have:

```
window.location = getBaseURL() + "site/writeToDatabase/" + splittedLatitude[0] + "/" + splittedLatitude[1]
        + "/" + splittedLongitude[0] + "/" + splittedLongitude[1] + "/";
```

so now the browser goes to (just an example with fake coordinates) www.mysite.com/index.php/site/writeToDatabase/47/707223/16/054322

now my writeToDatabase method in site controller reads those segments (I use codeigniter so it is really easy to read segments of URL). After I read segments, I concat first part of latitude and second part of latitude, and also put a dot "." in between (so in this example I get 47.707223 and 16.54322), and I do the same with the longitude.. then when I write those data to database, I get weird numbers in my database, also if one of my segments begins with zero (just like in my example above), the zero gets removed so from 054322 I get 54322, and that leads to 16.54322 just like in the example above :)

now this problem with strange numbers only occurs if I try to write to database whole coordinates.. if I just write first part of longitude, or just second part of longitude (same goes for latitude) everything goes well and correct value gets written..

anyone else has a solution to this problem? I'm all out of ideas

Comment: numbers with leading zeroes are usually interpreted as octal numbers, if you're keeping the fractional parts separate, check that the "weird" bits are not decimalized octal numbers.

Comment: It looks like you aren't concerned about numbers, but strings. Leading zeroes do not affect a number in any way.

Comment: Why don't you just send the parameters as they are like this: `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/?lat=47.11&lng=5.012`

Comment: I agree with @fdomig - if splitting the numbers at the decimal point causes problems, then don't do it.

Comment: @fdomig thanks, I will give that a shot, it seems legit :)
can I add you guys some reputation points or something? I can't see that option

Comment: @Drag0 you got an answer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just send the parameters as they are like this:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar/?lat=47.11&lng=5.012
```

That does fix that issue.

However you can do it your way (since these are strings not integers) with simple string concatenation like this.

```
$lat = $_GET['first'] . '.' . $_GET['second];
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work..
now my url looks like this:

www.mysite.com/index.php/site/writeToDatabase/?lat=45.7071587&lng=16.0575276

and via Codeigniter I do this:

$locationGPS = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->db->query('UPDATE table SET locationGPS=' . $locationGPS . ' WHERE id=' . $id);

damn..

Answer (score 0):

An integer will never have a leading zero, if you need one - create CHAR fields, not INTs (and don't typecast, in case you do that manually as well).